# random number doesn't change in loop

Tags: javascript

The random number doesn't change using `while` loop. When I want to play again, the `randomnumber` is still the same.

Here's the code:

```
randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
while(true){
    yourguess=prompt("Please Enter A Number Between 1-10");
    if(randomnumber==yourguess){
        alert("Good Job");
        answer=prompt("Do You Want To Play More ? Y/N")
        if(answer=="Y"){

        }else{
            break;
        }
    }else{
        alert("Not Matched "+ randomnumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should repeat the generation of the random number when a next game is requested:

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
while (true) {
    var yourguess = prompt("Please Enter A Number Between 1-10");
    if (randomnumber == yourguess) {
        alert("Good Job");
        var answer = prompt("Do You Want To Play More ? Y/N")
        if (answer == "Y") {
            randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10); //<---
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Not Matched "+ randomnumber);
    }
}
```

Make sure to declare your variables (with `var`, `let` or `const`).

Comment: Works fine for me. What is not working @PeterDarmis?

Comment: do you get a random number the first place? Please check the fiddle sir it does not work, it gets the same number always. In addition if any time in any prompt i as a user would want to cancel and close prompt id does not work.

Comment: I checked the code when I posted, and ran the fiddle. It works as intended. The random number changes *only* when a new game starts -- which is the desired behaviour -- and that *does* happen. There was no cancel requirement in the OP. It is quite harsh to call this *"not working"*. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate that `randomnumber` inside the `while` loop:

```js
while(true){
 var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

 yourguess=prompt("Please Enter A Number Between 1-10");
 
 if(randomnumber==yourguess){
    alert("Good Job");
    answer=prompt("Do You Want To Play More ? Y/N")
    if(answer=="Y"){

    }else{
        break;
    }
}else{
    alert("Not Matched "+ randomnumber);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different random number each time the loop is executed, you need to generate the `randomnumber` inside the while loop.

```
while (true) {
    let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    yourguess = prompt("Please Enter A Number
            Between 1 - 10");
    if (randomnumber == yourguess) {
        alert("Good Job");
        answer = prompt("Do You Want To Play More ? Y/N")
        if (answer == "Y") {

        } else {
            break;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Not Matched " + randomnumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `randomnumber` a function and call it on loop start. In addition your code snippet was changed a bit in order not to get stuck in a loop of un-closing prompt windows, what was missing is a small part that checks what happens when user does not provide an answer or clicks the `cancel` button.

```js
var randomnumber = function() { return Math.floor(Math.random()*10); }
while(true){
    let number = randomnumber();
    yourguess=prompt("Please Enter A Number Between 1-10");
    if(!yourguess) {
    break;
    }
    if(number===parseInt(yourguess)){
        alert("Good Job");
        answer=prompt("Do You Want To Play More ? Y/N");
        if(!RegExp("y","gi").test(answer) || !answer){
            break;
        }
    }else{
        alert("Not Matched "+ number);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how a guess-a-number game works: the number should not change until it is guessed.

Comment: so basically you are proposing that in a guess-a-number game the number should be always static? Where is the difficulty in guessing? Also this is the question description `The random number doesn't change using while loop. When I want to play again, the randomnumber is still the same.` and not to mention title `random number doesn't change in loop` so i guess i am wrong. @trincot

Comment: @trincot What i mean is that when a user does not find the number, he/she actually re-plays the game of `find-the-number` so therefor the number should change, `always`.

Comment: The key is in what OP says *"When I want to **play again**, the randomnumber is still the same"*. So OP needs that when they play *again* (a new game after typing "Y") they want a newly generated number. But that does not mean that every time they guess wrong the number would need to change... that would be a quite frustrating game! You would try 1 to 10 and maybe still not have guessed it. If I were such player I would look for a different game. Note also that the OP accepted my answer, which seems to indicate I have the correct understanding of their requirements.

Comment: @trincot your snippet works after a user types `Y`. But... when the game starts a random number is picked say `1`. I type `4` and get the message that i was wrong. So in order for me to be asked if i want to continue the game by typing `Y` i have to write the correct answer `1` that i saw earlier in the error message `Not Matched Try Again 1`, and then be prompted with the question if i want to continue. Does the above sound correct or you? If yes then i can't argue with someone that wants to be right always. You are wrong here and you know it, there are more actions than needed.

Comment: @trincot in the end it does not matter since the OP chose what he wanted. Thank you, whatever. Please lets not discuss this anymore.

Comment: In that case, consider to remove the downvote from my answer. ;-)